# Qual a diferença da "string_view" para a "string" e qual se deve preferir?

Tags: c++, string, stl, c++17

Qual a diferença da nova classe do C++17 `string_view` para a `string`?

Em qual situações é indicado o uso da `string_view` em vez da `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `string_view` é uma referência simples para uma `string`. Essa última tem um objeto com os dados que é uma sequência de caracteres. A primeira tem um ponteiro para a `string` e quantos caracteres é seu tamanho.

O ponteiro não precisa ser para o primeiro caractere e quantidade não precisa pegar todos os caracteres seguintes. Então é uma forma de *substring* mas que não copia os dados para outro objeto, e não toma propriedade do objeto original. É uma forma de manter o acesso mais eficiente.

O objeto `string_view` não permite que faça alterações no objeto que ele referencia, então ele é considerado imutável e não tem problemas de concorrência.

Sempre que precisar fazer referência ao objeto *string* ou parte dele sem precisa mudá-lo ou ter com algo separado ele é mais interessante.

[Fizeram alguns testes](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-of-stdstring-view-vs-stdstring-from-c1):

[image: Substr com view é muito mais rápido ~20X]

Mas depende de implementação. Veja que dependendo do compilador a mesma operação de *split* pode ser melhor ou pior. O primeiro usa GCC e o segundo usa Clang.

[image: Com Split é um pouco mais lento]

[image: Mas não no Clang]

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sobre essa parte: O objeto string_view não permite que faça alterações no objeto que ele referencia, então ele é considerado imutável e não tem problemas de concorrência. 

Então a string_view é como se fosse uma const string?

Outra coisa, existe varias fontes na internet dizendo que a string_view não usa alocação dinâmica, como isso é possível?

Comment: É porque, como já dito, a memória alocada pertence a outro objeto, a verdaderua string. Não posso garantir como é a implementação real, mas eu imagino a string_view como sendo um simples ponteiro char* acompanhado de um int indicando o número de caracteres.

Comment: Pode-se vê-lo como `const string`, embora ele seja menos que isto. Se prestar atenção eu falei que ele é só um ponteiro e um tamanho, pra que alocar só para isto? Guardar na própria variável, é tamanho pequeno, conhecido, fixo, não tem problemas de *slashing*, não precisa de herança, nada. E como o @marcus falou a provável implementação (nada na especificação exige que seja assim).